# Insufficient authorisation to lst in SAS batch job

Tags: sas

Today I faced a problem and solved it, but I am not quite sure why the problem occured.
We have a SAS batch job:

```
/path_to_script/sasbatch.sh -log /some_path/Logs/replication_#Y.#m.#d_#H.#M.#s.log -batch -noterminal -logparm "rollover=session" -sysin /another_path/macros/replication.sas
```

And today the job fell over with error:

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access /sas_path/sasconfig/Lev1/SASApp/replication.lst.
```

I found that the cause of error was `NOPRINT` statement was not present at one of `PROC SQL` statements. After embedding `NOPRINT` inside `PROC SQL` header it worked normally.

So what role does `NOPRINT` really act in SAS job and why does it cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOPRINT` prevents anything to be written to the lst file. The lst file is the batch equivalent of the output window. Anything that would get written to the output window in an interactive session (because ODS LISTING is active) will be written to the lst file. I always run the batch jobs with `NOPRINT`

Answer (score 3):

**Error diagnosis**

You haven't set the `-print` option in your SAS batch job, so it chooses to write to the default directory. The user submitting the job doesn't have write access to this directory:

> /sas_path/sasconfig/Lev1/SASApp

**NOPRINT option & typical uses**

The `NOPRINT` option on the `PROC SQL` statement suppresses any output from the SQL Procedure. You must have a statement in your SQL procedure that is producing output, typically this is something similar to:

```
select col1 into :c1
from table;
```

Which produces output unnecessarily, as it is creating a macro variable called c1 that can be used elsewhere in the program.

**Resolutions**

Either set `NOPRINT`, or set the `-print` option in your batch jobs to a writable directory, and review/delete the output files as necessary.